# Image citations in Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, plagiarism

I just ran across [a documentation example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3064/arrays/17455/multidimensional-arrays#t=201608040005203015001) that has an un-cited image that appears to have originated from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02e7z943.aspx). Just a sanity check, but is this something that should be flagged as plagiarism or just edited with the citation?

I was also searching around in Meta and can't seem to find what the SO policy on image citations *is*.  Is there such a policy somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see this before reviewing, you should reject as "Copied Content", with a link to either the image or the page it's on.

Unfortunately, it's too late for that. It's unacceptable to leave the image as is, but you have two choices:

- Remove the image, with an edit summary saying it was plagiarized from <link>

  - This is the easiest, safest option.
- See what licence the original was under. If it can be legally used here, add a proper citation.

  - If the image adds little to the Docs, consider removing it instead.

After taking one of those two options, you can flag if you want (don't flag in Documentation, since those aren't real flags), but at this point moderators are limited. The best they can do is suspend the user entirely.

Whenever an edit adds an image, it's best to at least try to run a [reverse image search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en), ensuring you replace the keywords that Google guesses (they're usually too broad to be helpful). I have found quite a few cases of plagiarism this way.